# txt file that I download is empty

Tags: php, file-io

The code below is for two purposes
1) I save a text file on my server in a folder named "backup_db" its working fine mean when I open that text file it contain all the data

2) At the same time i also make this file downloadable for a user so that he could download it for himself and could save it on his hard disk and according to my wish its downloading but unfortunately the .txt file saved on my hard disk is, when open its empty and i don't know why please help me out

//save file

```
$handle = fopen('backup_db/db-backup-'.date('d-m-Y_H-i-s').'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.txt','w+');

$rr = fwrite($handle,$re);

//fclose($handle);

$ww = "db_backup".$rr.".txt"; 

//$handle = "";

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode($ww));   

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

header('Content-Type: application/download');

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');}}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the right file name? the file you are creating is called: `'backup_db/db-backup-'.date('d-m-Y_H-i-s').'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.txt'` while the file you are sending is: `"db_backup".$rr.".txt"` ($rr is the number of bytes written to the file...)

Comment: yes you are right Mr. Yaniro. OK then what u suggest me to do?? it will be better if u edit my existing code so that i could easily pass through it

Comment: now both the files have same name mean the one on server and the one on my hard disk "db-backup-test" but still i am facing the same problem

Comment: Luc is right, just do `readfile( $fileName );` after your send the headers

Comment: i did what all you guys said but now it give me warning like 

"<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(db_backup1546.txt) [<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>E:\VertrigoServer\www\accucarecanda\admin\class_inlcude.php</b> on line <b>120</b><br />
"

Comment: you can download any file unless otherwise it exists in server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only set the HTTP header but did not write the file into the response body. Use either [`fpassthru()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) or [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to write the content of the file directly to the response.

Sample (taken from php.net)

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

---

BTW:
Settings the same header multiple times simply overwrites the value set before unless you set the second parameter of `header()` to false.

Your code

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/download');
```

results in the following header:

```
Content-Type: application/download
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending a file namein the header  just gives the user a suggested filename. Try echoing out the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this**
ex :

```
$filename = urlencode($fileName); //download.txt
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename. "\";" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
header("Content-Length: $size")
```

where `$size` is size of yout file in bytes.

Comment: No you don't. PHP does this for you.